# Can I avoid files being marked as delete in target folder when running p4 copy command?

Tags: perforce

I am running p4 copy command on folder
ex: p4 copy c:\source c:\target

When I do that, files in source folder are correctly copied into the target folder but existing files in target folder are being marked as delete.
Can I avoid files being marked as delete in target folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p4 copy` forces the target to become a copy of the source -- existing files are overwritten with content from the source, and if they don't exist in the source at all, they are deleted.

If you don't want the target to be a perfect copy of the source (i.e. you want it to be a combination of the source with what's already in the target), you may want to use the `p4 merge` command instead, e.g.:

```
p4 merge C:\source\... C:\target\...
p4 resolve -am
p4 resolve -at
```

`p4 merge` will only operate on files from the source that have not already been fully merged into the target, meaning that it will entirely skip files that don't exist in the source even if they do exist in the target.

`p4 resolve -am` will attempt to auto-merge all the files, and `p4 resolve -at` will accept "theirs" (the source) for any files that didn't auto-merge.

If you do want to use `p4 copy` but you don't want any files to be opened for delete, do the copy and then revert the deleted files:

```
p4 -F %depotFile% fstat -Ro -F action=delete C:\target\... | p4 -x - revert
```